# Printing the Developer Story by PDF in Timeline format

Tags: discussion, developer-story, sharing, print

The developer story is great, and I get good feedback when I use it.

But that mostly comes when I send someone to the URL of the developer story.  This is not always possible, when I'm asked to upload it to a job-application portal.

When I go to print it, the nice graphical formatting goes away, and it's a bunch of blocks that are grouped by the type of thing, not the time it appeared vertically in the timeline.

Can the visual appearance and order of the timeline view be better preserved when printing [to PDF]?

Answer (score 2):

I used the approach in following SO answer (Google Chrome only): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29962072/10473469, Section *Chrome v52+*. Setting *Emulate CSS Media* to *screen* did the job.

[image: Google DevTools]

The print view looks like the following:

[image: Print Preview]